# List item numbers don't transfer to new document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm creating a function that will transfer text that a user is currently selecting from one document to another.

It works fine most of the time, but when I try to transfer list items, as seen on this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrKCo.jpg), the list item numbers disappear.

After being transferred to the target document, the list items from the last image now look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoGSi.jpg).

**Is there a way to make sure the numbers get transferred, or at least recreate them in an efficient way?
Thanks!**

---

### Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
function sendToDoc() {
  var currentDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(a different documents url);
  var body = targetDoc.getBody();

  //if you are selecting some text, this function will transfer your selection into the target document

  if(currentDoc) {
    var totalElements = currentDoc.getRangeElements();
    
    //for each element in your selection

    for( var index = 0; index < totalElements.length; ++index ) {
      var element = totalElements[index].getElement().copy();
      var type = element.getType();
      
      
      //gets the element type and transfers it over to the target doc

      if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
        body.appendParagraph(element);
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
        body.appendTable(element);
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){ //this is where the list items get transferred
        body.appendListItem(element);
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE ){
        body.appendImage(element);
      }
      else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.HORIZONTAL_RULE ){
        body.appendHorizontalRule();
      }
      else {
        
      }
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [GlyphType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type) to `NUMBER`:

```
 body
  .appendListItem(element)
  .setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.NUMBER)
```